# pyspark and python not installed as part of HDP 2.6.0.3-8 stack

Tags: pyspark, hdp, spark2

I have a HDP cluster where 2.6.0.3 is installed. In one of the gateway node which is not attached to the Ambari, I installed hdp stack. with the installation I got the spark2 installed. that is all fine so far. But when I looked into it, I did'nt find any python or pyspark package in it ? Do I have to install them seperately ? why does the pyspark package did'nt install with spark2 from the HDP 2.6.0.3-8 stack ?

Answer (score 0):

If the first installation does'nt install python in spark2. you have to do it seperately.
First check using the command 'yum search spark2', you will see some list of packages that include python. take that python package name and do 'yum install python_package_name'. It will install python under /usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-8/spark2/ folder.